# Perl6: Picking a pair of coordinates

Tags: raku

I was trying to find a way to print a random list of coordinates, without any duplicates, given a min and max value for both dimensions.

Though I am having having a hard time understanding the 'X' and '>>' exactly does or means. Can anyone help explain this?

```
my $a=3;
my $b=3;

for (^$a X ^$b)>>.Array.pick(*) -> [$a,$b]
{
    print "($a, $b)";
}
```

Output (example):

```
(1,1)(0,1)(0,2)(1,2)(0,0)(2,2)(2,1)(1,0)(2,0)
```

Comment: The `>>.Array` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation on `X`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/X).
[Documentation on `>>`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_Operators).
Although you don't need `>>.Array` in this case, as Brad already pointed out.

Assuming that you will never exceed the number of possible coordinate permutations, you might find this to be better performing (for low number of coordinates versus number of permutations):

```perl6
my $a = 3;
my $b = 3;
my $number = 5; # must be less than $a * $b
for (($a.rand.Int,$b.rand.Int) xx *).unique(:as(*.Str)).head($number) {
    .gist.print
}
```

The `($a.rand.Int,$b.rand.Int) xx *` creates an infinite [`Seq`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq) of random coordinate pairs.  The [`.unique(:as(*.Str))`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/unique) makes sure we filter the unique coordinates out, as per their [`.Str`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str) representation.  Then [`.head`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/head) just takes the first 5 found.

This prevents having to build all permutations.  Then again, if you do need them all, then your way (minus the `>>.Array`) is pretty much how I would do it.

Future versions of Rakudo Perl 6 may not need the `:as(*.Str)`, which would make this better performing still.